# This should be urgent closed!

Tags: support, status-declined

[How much of this image do I need to modify in order to avoid copyright violation?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/8289/1272)

OP is explaining for not having permission on the material his post is related to.
(unkowingly, probably but that doesn't matter)

So the contents he is embedding and linking to he had no permission to publicate and posting it here also violates the terms of the CC BY-SA 3.0 license, as I mentioned in a comment. So his post should be removed as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Please familiarise yourself with the [Terms](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

From the [Copyright Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal#15CopyrightPolicy) (**not** the full clause):

> 5. A statement made under penalty of perjury that the information provided in the notice is accurate and that the Notifying Party is authorized to make the complaint on behalf of the copyright owner.

The [content policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy):

> **Copyright**. Using copyrighted material does not constitute infringement in all cases. In general, however, users should be careful when using copyrighted content without the permission of those who created it. It is our policy to [respond to notices of alleged infringement](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#designatedagent) that comply with the [Digital Millennium Copyright Act ("DMCA")](http://www.loc.gov/copyright/legislation/dmca.pdf).

At this stage I won't be taking action on this question.

Comment: This means someone declaringg he has no clue about he is allowed to post something, is not contradicting with the terms of the CC BY-SA 3.0?

Comment: You could ask a question on the main site. I've merely set out what the process for the copyright owner to have infringing content removed is, and it's not a meta post - we're not in the business of removing content based on an unrelated third party with no proprietary interest in it. The user also did not state that they did not have permission, merely that they did not want to use the same images in their game so that they would not violate copyright in their game. For all you know, they emailed the game developer and got their permission to use the image to ask this question.

Comment: Thats what I'm actually phrasing. Ok, I see it not beeing an argument, but one could reasonable assume, that if he had emailed him, he also jsut could ahve asked him about beeing ok with the way hes using it.

Comment: Well, then there's no problem, is there? You don't know if they have permission to use it - maybe they do. You don't need permission to use any material that has copyright on it - only if no exception or limitation exists. **Ask a question on the main site** about whether one can licence content which they don't own.

Comment: As I said, thats what I'm actually phrasing: http://law.stackexchange.com/q/8308/1272

Answer (score 2):

1. We [the community] don't respond to copyright violations.
2. Umm... He's linking the image to show. I'm quite sure that's okay. People quote websites and books all the time - are they violating copyright?

Comment: I'm expecting some support to your answer of the community before I'll accept this is really the networks policy on copyright violations.